# Following memory positions in assembly code

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pic18

I need to find out what the purpose of this code is and how can I follow what the value of the memory positions are?

I've gotten the few few lines as down then I'm lost

```
MOVLW     3             ; W = 3
MOVWF     0x05, A       ; (0x05) = 3
MOVLW     1             ; W = 1
MOVWF     0X10, A       ; (0x10) = 1

ORG 0X000
GOTO      MAIN
MAIN: 
CLRF      TRISC, A
MOVLW     3
MOVWF     0x05, A
MOVLW     1
MOVWF     0X10, A

B1: 
MULLW     2
MOVF      PRODL, 0, A
MOVWF     LATC, A
MOVWF     0X10, A
DECFSZ    0X05, 1, A
BRA       B1

FIN:
BRA       FIN
END
```

Comment: have you tried to use a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

```
MOVLW 3         ; W = 3
MOVWF 0x05, A       ; (0x05) = 3
MOVLW 1         ; W = 1
MOVWF 0X10, A       ; (0x10) = 1
```

As you've already deciphered :)

```
ORG 0X000
GOTO MAIN
```

Presumably an artifact of disassembly? These skip over the reset vector. You can ignore these lines and needn't use them in any code you're writing.

```
MAIN: CLRF TRISC, A
```

The MAIN label isn't syntactically significant. CLRF TRISC clears the *tri-state buffer* for port C, setting all of the C pins as outputs.

```
MOVLW 3
MOVWF 0x05, A
MOVLW 1
MOVWF 0X10, A
```

0x05 = 3 and 0x10 = 1

```
B1: MULLW 2
MOVF PRODL, 0, A
MOVWF LATC, A
MOVWF 0X10, A
DECFSZ 0X05, 1, A
BRA B1
```

This section is a loop. Each iteration we double the W register (multiply it by 2). The result is stored in the PRODL and PRODH registers, and we move the contents of PRODL (the low byte of the result) back into W.

We then copy this into LATC (the port C output) and 0x10.

Afterwards, we subtract 1 from 0x05.

BRA B1 takes us back to the beginning of the loop.

```
FIN: BRA FIN
END
```

These will never be reached so don't do anything.